# Silverstripe selected in DropdownField

Tags: php, silverstripe

How can I set a default selected value in `Silverstripe` using `DropdownField`. I have list of categories and I want to set a default selected item, but I don't know how to do it. Looking on SS API for DropdownField, there does not exist method for `selected`.

**Here is my code:**

```
DropdownField::create('CategoryID', 'Categories')->setSource(Category::get()->map('ID', 'Name'))->setEmptyString('Chose category'),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ->setValue with your value (e.g. $iSelectedCategoryID) like this...

```
DropdownField::create('CategoryID', 'Categories')
    ->setSource(Category::get()->map('ID', 'Name'))
    ->setEmptyString('Chose category')
    ->setValue($iSelectedCategoryID)
```